# Use Java object as a temp table within a BGQ query

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I need to use below query to insert/update a row in a gbq table

```
MERGE INTO `target_table` AS target
USING `source_table` AS source
ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    target.name = source.name,
    target.age = source.age
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (name, age)
  VALUES (source.name, source.age);
```

Now the problem is I have target_table in GBQ but for source_table I have Java object as input parameter.
I am having trouble to use Java object as source_table.

Is there even a way I can do this? I am bit lost.

Comment: What does your Java Object look like?  Likely what you will have to do is create a table to use as the merge source_table and populate it with the data that is currently contained in your Java Object.  I am also assuming that your Java Object is an instance of an object contained in a Java application rather than some serialized form kept currently on storage.

Comment: yeh Java Object of a simple class with 3 fields id,name and age.